# Error with passing arguments in a template using bottle Framework

Tags: html, mysql, templates, bottle

I am trying to make a web application by using bottle Framework but when I pass an argument, which is a tupleelement I get this error on my browser:

```
  % for row in result:
NameError: name 'result' is not defined.
```

```
@get('/USA')
def USA():
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root', passwd='songs', database = 'songs',port=3306, charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
command = cur.execute("SELECT cd,tragoudistis FROM singer_prod")
res = cur.fetchall()
result = dict(res)

return template("result2.tpl")
```

Edit:
Finally, I found the answer.For anyone who is interested i changed the final line with this:

```
return template("result2.tpl",result2 = result)
```

Comment: You need to show us the contents of `result2.tpl` for us to be able to help.

Comment: Also don't put your root db password on the internet! :)

Comment: Ok I'll change the password.